# Test string based on specific rules

Tags: vba, excel

I am setting up a transaction system. The user will transact 2D barcodes.
For each model, the barcode should meet specific requirements. See the table below.

[image]

So based on above, `PRT0001`'s 4th character should be 2, 3, or 4.

For `PRT0002`, the 4th character should be >=3, the 12th character should be `A`, the 13th should be `A` and the 14th should be `B`.

Now, for `PRT0005` it is even more complicated.
The 5th and 6th characters should go together wherein the value should be in the range of `01-52` (number of weeks in a year).
The 13th and 14th characters should be what's within the list.

Now, I am planning on setting up a table in Access where I'll put all the rules somewhat similar to above format and then just retrieve the rules when the user selects the `PartNum`.

I am planning on retrieving the `CharPos` field, transfer it to array which will be the basis of what character position to inspect. Do the same for the `CharRes` field to get the characters to compare to. Something like:

```
Dim arr1, arr2, myrules, j, c
myrules = rec.GetRows 'I'll retrieve the rules in Access using ADO

arr1 = Split(myrule(0, 0), ",")
arr2 = Split(myrule(1, 0), ",")

For j = Lbound(arr1) To Ubound(arr1)
    c = Mid(barcode, j, 1)
    If Not c = arr2(j) Then MsgBox "Invalid": Exit For
Next
```

This is ok, considering `PRT0004` above. However, other rules are a bit complicated. I need to employ a standard way of evaluating the rules so that I can produce a common function or sub routine that I can *call* within my main sub. I thought I cannot achieve such using above approach.

So my question is, do you guys have any suggestion on how I'll do this better?
This maybe too much, but let's just say I'm just consulting my old buddies (the community) which might have a better idea or approach.

BTW, I am limited to using Excel as the front-end (user interface) and Access as the back-end (database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fixed case, [Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237785/bond) is right. I think that his answer is not compatible for this problem. Because, for sure case, we can use **Regular Expression**. But, for this question, all conditions are store in database and user can add conditions and parts. So, It is not OK.

Therefore, I think and tried in another way. But it is a pure VBA code. Here what I tried for you:

```
Public Function checkString(inputString As String, length As Integer, position As String, rule As String) As String

    Dim message As String

    'Set blank to message
    message = ""

    'Check string length
    If Len(inputString) <> length Then

        Call addMessage(message, "The length must be " & length & ".")

    'Check conditions
    Else

        Dim positionList, ruleList, tempRuleList
        Dim startPos, endPos, posRange, posIndex
        Dim index, tempIndex As Integer
        Dim tempRule, flag As String
        Dim isValid As Boolean
        Dim fromRange, toRange As Integer

        'get position list
        positionList = Split(Trim(position), ",")

        'get rule list
        ruleList = getRuleList(rule, UBound(positionList))

        'Looping position list
        For index = LBound(positionList) To UBound(positionList) Step 1

            'get the rule
            tempRule = ruleList(index)

            'Condition for operator case (for example: >=3)
            If InStr(1, tempRule, "<") > 0 Or InStr(1, tempRule, "=") > 0 Or InStr(1, tempRule, ">") > 0 Then

                If InStr(1, tempRule, "<") > 0 Then
                    flag = flag & "l"
                End If

                If InStr(1, tempRule, ">") > 0 Then
                    flag = flag & "g"
                End If

                If InStr(1, tempRule, "=") > 0 Then
                    flag = flag & "e"
                End If

                'Remove operators
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, ">", "")
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, "<", "")
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, "=", "")

                'check
                Select Case flag

                    Case "le":
                        If Not Mid(inputString, positionList(index), 1) <= tempRule Then
                            Call addMessage(message, "The character from position " & positionList(index) & " must be less or equal with " & tempRule & ".")
                        End If

                    Case "ge":
                        If Not Mid(inputString, positionList(index), 1) >= tempRule Then
                            Call addMessage(message, "The character from position " & positionList(index) & " must be greater or equal with " & tempRule & ".")
                        End If

                    Case "l":
                        If Not Mid(inputString, positionList(index), 1) < tempRule Then
                            Call addMessage(message, "The character from position " & positionList(index) & " must be less than " & tempRule & ".")
                        End If

                    Case "g":
                        If Not Mid(inputString, positionList(index), 1) > tempRule Then
                            Call addMessage(message, "The character from position " & positionList(index) & " must be greater than " & tempRule & ".")
                        End If

                End Select

            'Condition for range case (for example: [2-5])
            ElseIf InStr(1, tempRule, "[") > 0 Then

                'remove brakets
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, "[", "")
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, "]", "")

                'split by comma
                tempRuleList = Split(Trim(tempRule), "-")

                fromRange = CInt(tempRuleList(0))
                toRange = CInt(tempRuleList(1))

                If InStr(1, positionList(index), "-") > 0 Then
                    posRange = Split(Trim(positionList(index)), "-")

                    startPos = posRange(0)
                    endPos = posRange(1)
                Else
                    startPos = positionList(index)
                    endPos = positionList(index)
                End If

                For posIndex = startPos To endPos Step 1
                    posVal = posVal & Mid(inputString, posIndex, 1)
                Next posIndex

                If Not (CInt(posVal) <= fromRange And CInt(posVal) >= toRange) Then
                    Call addMessage(message, "The character from positions " & positionList(index) & " must be between " & ruleList(index) & ".")
                End If

            'Condition for set of value case (for example: {2,4,5})
            ElseIf InStr(1, tempRule, "{") > 0 Then

                If InStr(1, positionList(index), "-") > 0 Then
                    posRange = Split(Trim(positionList(index)), "-")

                    startPos = posRange(0)
                    endPos = posRange(1)
                Else
                    startPos = positionList(index)
                    endPos = positionList(index)
                End If

                'remove brakets
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, "{", "")
                tempRule = Replace(tempRule, "}", "")

                'split by comma
                tempRuleList = Split(Trim(tempRule), ",")

                'looping positions
                For posIndex = startPos To endPos Step 1

                    'Reset isValid flag
                    isValid = False

                    'looping rule list
                    For tempIndex = LBound(tempRuleList) To UBound(tempRuleList) Step 1

                        If Mid(inputString, posIndex, 1) = tempRuleList(tempIndex) Then
                            isValid = True
                            Exit For
                        End If

                    Next tempIndex

                    If Not isValid Then
                        Call addMessage(message, "The character from position " & posIndex & " must be one of " & ruleList(index) & ".")
                    End If

                Next posIndex

            'Condition for must be one case (for example: A)
            ElseIf Mid(inputString, positionList(index), 1) <> tempRule Then

                Call addMessage(message, "The character from position " & positionList(index) & " must be " & tempRule & ".")

            End If

        Next index

    End If

    'Return message
    If message = "" Then
        checkString = "Valid"
    Else
        checkString = "The string '" & inputString & "' is not valid. Fixed the following error:" & vbNewLine & message
    End If

End Function

Private Function getRuleList(rule As String, count As Integer) As Variant

    Dim tempList, returnList
    Dim tempIndex, resultIndex As Integer

    'split by comma
    tempList = Split(Trim(rule), ",")

    'If there is no special condition, return list
    If count = UBound(tempList) Then

        returnList = tempList

    'Else process for special codition
    Else

        ReDim returnList(count) As String

        resultIndex = 0

        For tempIndex = LBound(tempList) To UBound(tempList) Step 1

            If InStr(1, tempList(tempIndex), "}") > 0 Then
                returnList(resultIndex) = returnList(resultIndex) & "," & tempList(tempIndex)
            Else
                returnList(resultIndex) = tempList(tempIndex)
            End If

            If InStr(1, tempList(tempIndex), "{") = 0 Then
                resultIndex = resultIndex + 1
            End If

        Next tempIndex

    End If

    'Return rule list
    getRuleList = returnList

End Function

Private Function addMessage(ByRef dest As String, ByVal message As String)

    If IsEmpty(dest) Or dest = "" Then
        dest = message
    Else
        dest = dest & vbNewLine & message
    End If

End Function
```

I know that there are many code line. So, let see below explanation for my code.

**Coding Explanation**

> **1."checkString"** method

```
It takes the following parameter:
inputString: the string for check
length     : the desired length for inputted string
position   : the position list which separated by comma
            ("{2,3,4}" and "[2-3]" are not valid for position but valid range like 2-3)
rule       : the rule list which separated by comma

It returns the result message as "Valid" for pass case.
And If it is not pass, error messages will come out.
```

> **2."getRuleList"** method
>
> This method is for what? Because the rules are separated by comma(,). But sometime it include range rules like **{2,3,4}**. So, we need to think about it. So, this method is used for getting separated rule list.
>
> **3."addMessage"** method
>
> This method is for adding messages because we can see one or more error (i.e. one or more position has wrong character).

I tested my method with the following code:

```
Public Sub testing()

    Dim returnMessage As String

    returnMessage = checkString("00465B", 6, "1,2-3,4-5,6", ">=1,[01-03],{4,5},A")

    If returnMessage <> "Valid" Then
        MsgBox returnMessage
    End If

End Sub
```

After running the code, I got the following message:

[image]

I believe, this code will be helpful for you. I already tested the code and it is OK for me.

If there is any problem or code error, let me know.

Comment: My first attempt is somehow similar to yours. Brute force VBA. And the reason is like what you've figure out. I need the user to be able to add new Parts with new rules. I just need to make sure they fill up the rules properly. I was not really expecting that you or anyone else would go the miles of actually coding it. Thanks mate.

Comment: OK...I do what you provide. If there is any changes or more requirement or any problem when using this code, tell me. I will help you.

Comment: I decided to go this route. Not exactly the same code, but the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

I would just store a regex pattern. Then you can just retrieve the pattern based on the part and test the barcode using the associated pattern.

For example, you could use the following patterns (assuming I didn't screw any of them up):

```
strPattern1 = "^\w{3}[2-4]\w{12}$"
strPattern2 = "^\w{3}[3-9]\w{7}AAB\w{3}$"
strPattern3 = "^\w{3}[4-9]\w{7}A\w{4}$"
strPattern4 = "^CD\w{9}A\w{4}$"
strPattern5 = "^\w{3}[4-9](0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[012])\w{5}E[26][FGH]\w{5}$"
```

The only tricky part is the week numbers but I think that pattern should work.

The `\w` will match `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` so, if you don't want the underscore and/or lowercase letters, you can replace `\w` with `[0-9A-Z]`.

To use it:

```
Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = strPattern1     ' Depending on the type of part

If re.Test(strBarcode) Then
    ' Checks out
Else
    ' Invalid
End If
```

Comment: Yeah, I was writing and testing regex atm as well. If I use this approach however, I would need to create a function that  produces the regex pattern automatically for cases the user needs to enroll a new part. That would be trickier. But yeah I was considering this approach as well. Thanks mate.

Comment: If a new part is enrolled, you'll have work to do using any type of solution, though, right? Somewhere you'll need to define the rules for the new part number. I guess it would just depend on your comfort level with creating the new regex pattern vs another solution.

Comment: `I guess it would just depend on your comfort level with creating the new regex pattern` True. I'm not strong in regex though but this is favorable considering I'll just set up 1 field in Access to store the patterns.

Comment: Yep, I think it would work out great for you. And I'm sure you could study the five patterns above to see how it could work for other (future) parts. If not, come back to SO and we'll help you out!